# deduce type of variable dependent on template function type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a template function:

```
// Overloaded functions, Class1In, Class1Out, Class2In and Class2Out
// are defined in the code.  
Class1Out Init(Class1In one) { ... }
Class2Out Init(Class2In two) { ... }

template <class A>
void f(A a, int retry_count) {
  B b = Init(a); // How to express B?
}
```

Question is how can I express `B`? I tried the following, but it errors out saying that compiler cannot deduce B when I call `f`

```
template <class A, class B>
void f(A a, int retry_count) {
  B b = Init(a); // compiler error: Cannot deduce template parameter B
}
```

I cannot really call `Init` outside of `f` because the function retries by calling itself and needs to create a new instance of `b` every time it is called.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: what about `auto` ?

Comment: @max66 am learning how to use templates, so did not even cross my mind....:/
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `auto`, but in general you can use this trick to determine the type `B`:

```
using outType = decltype(Init(std::declval<A&>()));
```

for your particular case you can also use the simpler format (thanks user max66):

```
using outType = decltype(Init(a));
```

This allows you to know the type of `b` without needing to instantiate it.

If you need to instantiate `b` then you can also try

```
auto b = Init(a);
using outType = decltype(b);
```

In the below code I show the use adding some boilerplate code.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Class1Out{};
class Class2Out{};

class Class1In{};
class Class2In{};


Class1Out Init(Class1In one);
Class2Out Init(Class2In two);

template <class A>
void f(A a, int retry_count) {

  using outType = decltype(Init(std::declval<A&>()));
  outType b = Init(a); // How to express B?
}


int main(){

    Class1In in1{};
    Class2In in2{};

    f(in1, 4);
    f(in2, 4);
}
```

For more info about `std::declval` and `decltype` please see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: Nice. But, in this case, `std::declval<A&>` seems to me superfluous. You have `a` so you can write `using outType = decltype(Init(a));`; should be OK.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I wanted to demonstrate a more general case.

Comment: A good point is a good point though, I edited my answer with your suggestion.